# Returning an Int from Alamofire Request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I've tried using the answers in some other Alamofire questions with no success. I am trying to return an int to initialize the number of cells in a tableView.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var numberOfItems: Int = 0

    MyAPI.RecentTransactions() {
        (items, error) in
        if items! != [] {
            numberOfItems = items!.count
        }
    }

    return numberOfItems
}
```

The method I am calling is:

```
class func RecentTransactions(completionHandler: ([Item]?, NSError?) -> ()) -> () {
    var allItems: [Item] = []
    Alamofire.request(.GET, my_url)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, jsonData, error) in

        let json = JSON(jsonData!)
        let transactions = json["transactions"]
        let transaction = transactions["transaction"]

        for (index: String, action: JSON) in transaction {
            let itemURL = NSURL(string: action["item_url"].string!)
            if let homeItem = self.itemFromJSONObject(action["payment_id"].int!, title: action["title"].string!,itemURL: itemURL!) {

                allItems.append(item)

            }
        }
        completionHandler(allItems, error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking it is not a good design to make a server call in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Basically you should be aiming for loading the data in `viewDidLoad()` having them as property holding the state, such as:

```
var items: [Item] = [] {
    didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And after you've done your call to the server, set your data to the new value and the tableView will automatically reload itself. Your method using Alamofire could look like this:

```
// as you initialize the array, it will never be nil, so no need for optional
class func RecentTransactions(completionHandler: ([Item], NSError?) -> Void) {
    var allItems: [Item] = []
    Alamofire.request(.GET, my_url)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, jsonData, error) in

        let json = JSON(jsonData!)
        let transactions = json["transactions"]
        let transaction = transactions["transaction"]

        for (index: String, action: JSON) in transaction {
            let itemURL = NSURL(string: action["item_url"].string!)
            if let homeItem = self.itemFromJSONObject(action["payment_id"].int!, title: action["title"].string!,itemURL: itemURL!) {

                allItems.append(item)

            }
        }
        completionHandler(allItems, error)
    }
}
```

No need to have unwanted return types as it is asynchronous.

Then you would call this method in your `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```
MyAPI.RecentTransactions() {
    (items, error) in
    self.items = items
}
```

And finally have your `numberOfRowsInSection` method like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}
```

This approach is much cleaner. Excuse me if I made a mistake with your private API, I couldn't really test the code.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! I am new to iOS development so thank you for help with the design as well.

Comment: I've been there too. Glad to be helpful.